# Android Fragment Menus

Tags: android, android-fragments, menu, menuitem, oncreateoptionsmenu

In an app activity, I have four different fragments. I have added menus to each fragment with

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {}
```

function. But when I swipe to next fragments, and come back to previous, the menu options of the next fragment, get added to the menu in the current visible fragment. Also added the first statement `menu.clear()` in the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` but no effect. Stuck at this issue.

Comment: listen the current fragment listener and update menu options from there

Answer (score 0):

Within each fragments `OnCreate` and `OnCreateView` method ensure you call `setHasOptionMenu(true)` as below.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

    ...
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    return rootView;
}
```

also check that you are calling `super.onCreateOptionsMenu`

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.list_menu, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```